# Sending info through API

Tags: php, api

I don't know the proper way to say this, so here is my issue.

I am dealing with an API that sends information to the server, from either web form or whatever in this format:
    `http://server/non_agent_api.php?source=test&user=6666&pass=1234`....
with a bunch more parameters.

Normally, I have dealt with API's that just send it with SOAP or REST, not in a URL like that. My question is how do I send that information using php or something. So if I wanted to take in a username and password from a webform, how do I send that link to the server without clicking on the URL itself.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP use

```
header("Location: TARGETURL");
```

Create the `TARGETURL` using the information sent from the form.
The Location Header makes the server to generate 302 Moved temporarily `HTTP` return code. The browser then sends the user to the `TARGETURL` transparently without any further interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` for that like,

Read [curl()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), here you can find a `class` which can be easily used.